# Assistance with SQL query

Tags: sql

Suppose we have 2 tables :

1. `Patients` (ID, name)
2. `Patients_Treatments` (PatientID, treatment_code)

I would like the query to retrieve all the patients who received at least all the treatments of patient with `id='999999999'`

I've tried many combinations and nothing worked, all I've got is patients who got at least one of '9999999999' treatments.

Comment: You should edit your query and include your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a self join and comparison in the `having` clause:

```
select pt2.patientId
from patient_treatments pt join
     patient_treatments pt2
     on pt.treatment_code = pt2.treatment_code and pt.patientid <> pt2.patientid
where pt.id = '999999999'
group by pt2.patientId
having count(pt2.treatment_code) = (select count(*) from patient_treatments pt where pt.id = '999999999');
```

Note:  this version assumes that there are no duplicates in `Patient_Treatments`.

If you have duplicates in the data, you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
having count(distinct pt2.treatment_code) = (select count(distinct pt.treatment_code) from patient_treatments pt where pt.id = '999999999');
```

Comment: @RonenB The `join` matches the treatments of each patient with the treatments of patient '9999999999' . The `having` part counts the number of treatments for patient '9999999999', and then filters all patientes who have the same amount of treatments.

Comment: @RonenB Important: As Gordon notes, this works only if the treatments have no duplicates. For example, if Patient 9999999999 got treatment A once, and treatment B twice, but patient 7 got treatment A twice and treatment B once, then both have three treatments in sum, and they have also matching joins, so you would get a **false match**.

Comment: We have duplicaetes in the table, for example the same patient can get the same treatment many times, because there is also a date of a treatment . How can we solve it ?

Comment: Looks as if you would need to select patients with treatments that matched patient 999999999 on treatment_code, then use COUNT(DISTINCT treatment_code) to see which patients had all of them - will try and post an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is

(1) Select treatment codes belonging to patient "999999999"

(2) Select only treatment records whose treatment code matches one of the treatment codes belonging to patient "999999999"

(3) Group these by patient_id

(4) Use a HAVING statement and COUNT (DISTINCT) to select only those Patient ID's which have the same number of different treatment codes as patient "999999999".

```
select pt.Patient_ID,count(distinct pt.treatment_code)
from
Patient_treatments pt
inner join
(select distinct treatment_code
 from 
 Patient_treatments pt
 where pt.Patient_ID="999999999"
 )t1
 on t1.treatment_code=pt.treatment_code
 where pt.Patient_ID<>"999999999"
 group by pt.Patient_ID
 having count(distinct pt.treatment_code)=
 (select count(distinct treatment_code) 
  from 
  Patient_treatments pt
  where pt.Patient_ID="999999999"
  );
```

With the following schema, only patient 1 is selected:-

```
  Create table Patient_Treatments
  (
    Patient_ID varchar(10),
    Treatment_code varchar(10)
    );


   Insert into Patient_Treatments
    values
    ("1","abc"),
    ("1","def"),
    ("1","def"),
    ("1","ghi"),
    ("2","abc"),
    ("2","def"),
    ("2","def"),
    ("3","ghi"),
    ("999999999","abc"),
    ("999999999","def"),
    ("999999999","ghi"),
    ("999999999","ghi")
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03a84b